# SetProperties function doesn't work for an DirectoryEntry

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

I got a Domain User DirectoryEntry instance, but can't update his properties like "company","department","manager"..etc.

Following are my code

public static void SetProperty(DirectoryEntry de, string PropertyName, string PropertyValue){
    if(PropertyValue!=null){
        if(de.Properties.Contains(PropertyName)){
            de.Properties[PropertyName][0]=PropertyValue; 
        }
        else{
            de.Properties[PropertyName].Add(PropertyValue);
        }
    }
}

The property doesn't change anyway after de.commitchanges(). And No errors/exceptions happen. Please help out.. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone has comments on that? If anywhere missed in the configuration? Any possible reasons? Thanks!

Comment: Find the problems now. You need derectoryEntry.commictchanges()after each properties change.